# XSL using matches and regular expressions

Tags: regex, xslt

I have a simple `for-each` statement that matches nodes using a regular expression. I am looking inside nodes for any matches of 4 or more digits.

```
<xsl:for-each select="//methods/body[matches(., '= \d{4}')]">
    <p><xsl:value-of select="." /></p>
</xsl:for-each>
```

I am trying the get the VALUE of the matched value - i.e. if `NodeA` contains "xxxx yyyy *12345* zzzz" and `NodeB` contains "aaa bb *88555* cccc", I would like to print the values `12345` and `88555`.

The code above will simply print the entire current NODE that matches.

Furthermore, I need to get distinct values. E.g. `xxx 12345`, `yyy 56789`, `zzz 12345` I would need the  result to be `12345` and `56789`.

Is the matching pattern the best way to accomplish this?  I got my initial (correct) set of nodes quickly, but stalled.

Comment: An example xml document would be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the test, `matches()` works well. For actually pulling out the values, `xsl:analyze-string` is better.

Example...

**XML Input**

```
<doc>
    <x>xxxx yyyy 12345 zzzz</x>
    <x>aaa bb 88555 cccc</x>
    <x>xxxx yyyy 12345 zzzz aaa bb 88555 cccc</x>    
</doc>
```

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <xsl:variable name="values">
            <xsl:for-each select="x[matches(.,'\d{4}')]">
                <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="\d{{4}}">
                    <xsl:matching-substring>
                        <xsl:sequence select="."/>
                    </xsl:matching-substring>
                </xsl:analyze-string>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:value-of select="distinct-values(tokenize($values,'\s'))" separator=", "/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
1234, 8855
```